# Visual studio 2013 change references to not use specific version?

Tags: visual-studio, reference

Is there a way to change all references in visual studio so that the specific version property is False. I have a TON of references that I would rather not have to go through by hand.

Comment: Select all of them at once?

Comment: Is there an easy way to go about doing that? I have 17 projects so control clicking them would take a while

Comment: I've used powershell scripts for things like this, though that will take more time than going through 17 projects individually.